# WebDriver get text

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, chrome-web-driver

I use WebDriver and ChromeDriver.
How i can fetch text from this speech bubble:

[[image: click to see picture 1]]

And code this speech bubble from website:

[image: click to see picture 2]

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Get it through the image data-id or class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use xpath to get it

```
 //img[@data-id='c085ede491334747f26718fc2e8009e3')]
```

You can use this code and try:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[@data-id='c085ede491334747f26718fc2e8009e3')]")).getAttribute("data-content");
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Simple use xpath to locate the element

Comment: Maybe it would be easier to download text from div?

Comment: @David I got your point but how?

Comment: @iamsankalp89 Of course, your example helped me. Please see my latest post in this thread.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like id is dynamic. You can try to use the phrase in data content for searching:

```
findElement(By.xpath(".//img[@data-content = "your text"])).getAttribute("data-content");
```

If you need to get text and validate it (e.g. text inside of data content can be different), you can search by class:

```
driver.findElement(By.className("smarty-tip-wrapper")).getAttribute("data-content");
```

Comment: Maybe it would be easier to download text from div?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is everything is included in the table? if i think well

[image: click to see]

Comment: I am unable to understand please tell, its better to ask another question as you post your question in answer area